# 1250 - Table 'taxrec' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list

Tags: mysql

I am trying `UNION ALL` to join two database query results. Here is my query

```
 SELECT taxrec.* FROM (

    SELECT taxrec.* FROM fa_244.0_trans_tax_details AS taxrec WHERE (taxrec.amount <> 0 OR taxrec.net_amount <> 0) AND !ISNULL(taxrec.reg_type) AND taxrec.tran_date >= '2014-03-03' AND taxrec.tran_date <= '2018-03-31'

 union all 

    SELECT  taxrec.* FROM  fa_244.1_trans_tax_details AS taxrec WHERE (taxrec.amount <> 0 OR taxrec.net_amount <> 0) AND !ISNULL(taxrec.reg_type) AND taxrec.tran_date >= '2014-03-03' AND taxrec.tran_date <= '2018-03-31' 

ORDER BY taxrec.trans_type, taxrec.tran_date, taxrec.trans_no, taxrec.ex_rate ) a
```

But it shows the error. Any help to fix the issue. #1250 Table 'taxrec'

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to this question. The problem is we can't use the Alias in the main query, because those are used in sub queries only.
Here is the solution for the problem.

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT taxrec.* FROM fa_244.0_trans_tax_details AS taxrec WHERE (taxrec.amount <> 0 OR taxrec.net_amount <> 0) AND !ISNULL(taxrec.reg_type) AND taxrec.tran_date >= '2014-03-03' AND taxrec.tran_date <= '2018-03-31'

union all 

SELECT  taxrec.* FROM  fa_244.1_trans_tax_details AS taxrec WHERE (taxrec.amount <> 0 OR taxrec.net_amount <> 0) AND !ISNULL(taxrec.reg_type) AND taxrec.tran_date >= '2014-03-03' AND taxrec.tran_date <= '2018-03-31' 

ORDER BY trans_type, tran_date, trans_no, ex_rate ) a
```

That's it.

<sub>*Added on behalf of question asker.*</sub>